# Reading and parsing large CSV file using 'non-repeatable' stream

Tags: mule, esb, mule4

Thanks to harshank bansal , Ryan Hoegg and aled for their suggestions and comments to an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281173/memory-issues-parse-a-large-csv-file-transform-to-json-and-then-call-a-third-p/72282266?noredirect=1#comment127740741_72282266)

Using Mule 4.4 community edition and on premise.

So based on comments am reading the large CSV file as a `non repeatable stream`

File is a CSV file but pipe separated:

```
101|John Saunders|19|M|Physics|Chemistry|Mechanics
102|Jim White|17|M|Languages|Art|Pottery
...
...
```

Once it is read am checking for empty file using `attributes.size == 0`
Now at this point using `Set Payload` with `deferred=true` .

In debug mode after this component the payload shows up as `java.io.PipedInputStream` ( which is fine , this is simply an observation )

Now am passing this payload to the `HTTP Request` component which calls a REST endpoint . Presently have mocked this  REST endpoint and am logging the payload received by this REST endpoint.

However the payload received by this REST endpoint is an empty array

Do I need to set any attribute on HTTP Request ? I can see properties such as `Request Streaming mode` , do we need to configure anything there ?

Another doubt is : how many times is the REST service expected to be called ? will it get called multiple times or only a single request ?

here is the complete code of what I have tried .

```
    <flow name="get:employee" >
    
        
        <set-variable value='#[now() as String { format: "ddMMuu" }]' doc:name="Set todays date as ddmmyy" doc:id="37de829b-bc84-44f6-88d9-e66c52fabe83" variableName="today"/>
        
            <file:read doc:name="Read emp file"  
                config-ref="File_Config" 
                path="/emp_large.unl" 
                outputMimeType="text/csv; streaming=true; header=false; separator=|" outputEncoding="UTF-8">
                <non-repeatable-stream />
            </file:read>
        
        <try doc:name="Try" >
                <choice doc:name="is the file empty ?" >
            <when expression="attributes.size == 0">
                <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Payload is empty " message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  Empty payload from file: #[vars.fileName] !" category="load.empData" />
                <raise-error doc:name="Raise error on empty file "  type="EMP:FILE_NOT_PRESENT_OR_EMPTY" description="Emp File  either empty or not received or error in reading file content" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
            <set-payload value='#[output application/json deferred=true&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;---&#10;&#10;&#10;payload map (value,index)-&gt;{&#10;    "id": value.column_0,&#10;    "name": value.column_1&#10;}]' doc:name="Set Payload"  />
            <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Submit products to Rest API"  config-ref="HTTP_Request_config" path="/emps" requestStreamingMode="NEVER">
                <non-repeatable-stream />
                <http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    
    "Host" : p('http_emp.host'),
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
}]]]></http:headers>
                <http:response-validator >
                    <http:success-status-code-validator values="200" />
                </http:response-validator>
            </http:request>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" category="load.empData" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  Successfully published emp data to XYZ , response received is : #[payload]"/>
            <error-handler >
                        <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Failure log" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId] error encountered after reading  file #[vars.fileName]  , caused by : #[error.detailedDescription]" category="load.empData"/>
                    
                    </on-error-continue>
                </error-handler>
            </try>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"  message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  processing emp data END:" category="load.empData"/>
        
    </flow>
```

Attaching screen print of the flow for easier visualisation:
[image]

**Edit1**: Pasting complete code below :

```
<flow name="get:employee" doc:id="feffbaae-2873-4248-a043-d51697083b75">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="10c9e0bb-7f18-42b8-9378-1225cb546641" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  processing emp data START:" category="send.empData"/>
        
        <set-variable value='#[now() as String { format: "ddMMuu" }]' doc:name="Set todays date as ddmmyy" doc:id="37de829b-bc84-44f6-88d9-e66c52fabe83" variableName="today"/>
        
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="0f182868-404c-491e-acab-88832b73d73e" category="send.empData" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  After successfully moving file "/>
        <until-successful maxRetries="${sftp.retry.attempts}" doc:name="Until Successful" doc:id="cec72a48-72b7-436d-a024-fb3986fb3432" millisBetweenRetries="${sftp.retry.frequency}">
            <file:read doc:name="Read emp file" doc:id="e77633d5-5f4f-43a9-862b-9d6076308c2a" 
                config-ref="File_Config" 
                path="C:\emp_large.unl" 
                outputMimeType="text/csv; streaming=true; header=false; separator=|" outputEncoding="UTF-8">
                <non-repeatable-stream />
            </file:read>
        </until-successful>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="438f9b64-8d66-4999-ac72-cdd7ade3cd0f" category="send.empData" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  After successfully Reading file "/>
        <try doc:name="Try" doc:id="c934788a-28db-4e49-a7cd-ee8eaff026ae" >
                <choice doc:name="is the file empty ?" doc:id="69c57e57-354c-4a01-9810-35fc4228d5d9">
            <when expression="attributes.size == 0">
                <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Payload is empty " doc:id="08decd27-c8dc-41e7-8c1d-f395f405b248" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  Empty payload from file!" category="send.empData" />
                <raise-error doc:name="Raise error on empty file " doc:id="ad6e2e62-09f2-4e4a-bc2c-99d7ce2c95c8" type="EMP:FILE_NOT_PRESENT_OR_EMPTY" description="Emp File  either empty or not received or error in reading file content" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Payload not empty" doc:id="606550aa-c59e-4ff4-ad15-026a8616845a" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  File not empty and contains #[sizeOf(payload)] rows" category="send.empData" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
            <set-payload value='#[output application/json deferred=true&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;---&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;  {"clientId": "abcd",&#10;"employees": payload map (value,index)-&gt;{&#10;    "id": value.column_0,&#10;    "name": value.column_1&#10;}&#10;}]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="5dba41e5-df65-42e3-8899-0c4abf8f8c16" />
            <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Submit products to XYZ" doc:id="575d1c2f-d20f-4174-b7e6-ad0074ea7eb9" config-ref="HTTP_Request_config" path="/emps" requestStreamingMode="AUTO" sendBodyMode="AUTO">
                <non-repeatable-stream />
                <http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    
    "Host" : p('http_emp.host'),
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
}]]]></http:headers>
                <http:response-validator >
                    <http:success-status-code-validator values="200" />
                </http:response-validator>
            </http:request>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="d3988977-bdda-4eac-bf88-508201582a78" category="send.empData" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  Successfully published product data to XYZ , response received is : #[payload]"/>
            <error-handler >
                    <on-error-continue enableNotifications="false" logException="false" doc:name="On Error Continue - Move emp file from processing to error folder" doc:id="a02560ca-77fb-443f-88b0-fcc27185ea7c" >
                        <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Failure log" doc:id="c4a10961-d853-4fc4-87d7-9b5c55750a7c" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId] error encountered after reading  file  , caused by : #[error.detailedDescription]" category="send.empData"/>
                    <until-successful maxRetries="${sftp.retry.attempts}" doc:name="Until Successful" doc:id="d8b3e71a-02fc-4c19-be7f-3851288b85a0" millisBetweenRetries="${sftp.retry.frequency}">
                        <sftp:move doc:name="Move file to error" doc:id="22b353e3-ec17-4df5-aa20-4055e0a6cf3b" config-ref="SFTP_Config" sourcePath="#[p('sftp.outputProcessingDir') ++ '/' ++ vars.fileName]" targetPath="${sftp.outputErrorDir}" createParentDirectories="false" overwrite="true"/>
                    </until-successful>
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="dcc9dd6b-0734-486d-b0c1-a9fc3fe64348" category="send.empData" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  successfully moved  file  to error folder"/>
                    </on-error-continue>
                </error-handler>
            </try>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="20453f8a-45ad-4e23-98d5-a03a66509b5d" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId]  processing emp data END:" category="send.empData"/>
        <error-handler >
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="false" logException="false" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="3fa169c0-92ad-431b-9440-a21448db4bce" type="RETRY_EXHAUSTED">
                <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="bf68b097-9b02-4770-b0f3-9972bc91a97f" message="Co-relationId  : #[correlationId] while processing emp file Error is : #[error.suppressedErrors[0].errorType] caused by #[error.suppressedErrors[0].detailedDescription]" category="send.empData"/>
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is another downside of using `non repeatable stream`. It is happening because the breakpoint that you put will consume the `InputStream` and you can only consume an input stream once. Therefore your `set-payload` will receive an empty payload when it executes. Having said that, I believe that the debugger should be smart enough to detect that payload is non repeatable stream and not consume it.

Try disabling the breakpoint, if everything else is set correctly, it should send the request to the HTTP Endpoint. If you want to see the payload you can try logging a few rows after the `set-payload` once, then remove the logger. (I know it does not sounds appealing, but currently it is the only option I can think off with the current version of Anypoint studio.)

**EDIT:** Another reason that you are sending an empty Array is because you are consuming the InputStream while logging the `sizeOf(payload)`. Therefore your `set-payload` is getting an empty Stream to consume.

For your question.

> how many times is the REST service expected to be called ? will it get called multiple times or only a single request ?

This basically uses [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). So the request is sent over a single request, but since the payload is not generated before sending the reqeust, it is sent in `chunks` until the request is finished.

Comment: thanks @harshank-bansal , am running anypoint studio without debugging , same result , request received at mock api is empty payload

Comment: Just noticed you had put `requestStreamingMode` as `NEVER`. Can you try with the default one i.e. `Auto`

Comment: no did not work also tried changing ```send body mode``` to AUTO . Rest api receiving empty array for payload

Comment: Will try to load your code in my local later to test it.

Comment: Can you update the xml in the question with your latest code? Seems like something is missing in error handler and also missing some component when compared to screenshot

Comment: sure updating now , i had omitted the error handler in pasted code earlier but will add complete code

Comment: The logger in the `otherwise` route of choice has `sizeOf(payload)` that is consuming your payload. Like I mentioned in the previous question that you can not use this. As it will consume the payload before it reaches the `set-payload` dw

Comment: this was the cause of empty payload , thank you ! another problem now encountered is a 413 but thats a separate issue will look into , please include your comments into a answer so I will accept it , many thanks !

Comment: also one more quick question , in HTTP Request - streaming strategy - assuming same logic applies , we should use ```Non repeatable stream``` is that correct ? also does this mean that HTTP request also is not loading entire payload into memory ? not sure how that is happening , but I am thinking mule avoids loading data into memory and post transformation offloads / dumps the payload to the REST client to handle ?

Comment: That Parameter (Streaming strategy in Advanced tab) is **NOT** related to request. It will effect how the code will consume the payload after you receive your response from the server. If it is not a large response, you should use the default repeatable stream.